# Bootstrap nav walker dropdown menus in mobile version collapsing whole menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Nav Walker with Bootstrap 3.0 to output the main nav menu, the structure of which is roughly:

- top level item

  - secondary item
  - secondary item
- top level item

  - secondary item
  - secondary item

And so on. The desktop version works fine. On the mobile version, the `button.navbar-toggle` opens the top level menu fine, but when I click on a top level item that has a sub menu, the submenu expands, but also collapses the top level menu.

Code for the Nav Walker and navbar-default:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/vanilla_3/assets/images/logotype.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Caring4Connor">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/vanilla_3/assets/images/logotype-xs.png" class="visible-xs-inline-block" alt="Caring4Connor">
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'main-nav',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

I've dug through the code and compared to working examples, but I can't seem to find anything that is causing this!

Comment: bootstrap 3.0 is a bit old.... you should upgrade to the latest bootstrap version (currently 3.3.6)

Comment: My mistake, it is 3.3.6 already.